# import {saveAs} from 'file-saver': CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts

Tags: angular, filesaver.js

After upgrading to Angular 10, my download [file-saver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) `saveAs` triggers the following compilation warning:

```
CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
```

The compiler also provides a [link to an explanation](https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies) and how to disable the warning. Instead of disabling the warning, is there a ES bundle implementation for the `saveAs` functionality?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use file-saver-es instead.

```
npm install -S file-saver-es
```

Then in your code import saveAs and other codes keep as before.

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver-es';
```

and if you're using typescript add following to your `tsconfig`:

```
"paths": {
      "file-saver-es": [
        "@types/file-saver"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: There is no `@types/file-saver-es`.

Comment: @MikhailOrlov see the edit about that !

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler it looks like there IS now a `@types/file-saver-es`

Answer (score 8):

I tried everything but nothing worked. So decided to shut angular up.

I added file-saver as an allowed commonjs dependancy in `angular.json` file.

```
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["file-saver"],
```

That goes in projects->architect->build->options.

Comment: Only hides the warning unfortunately.

Comment: You will not be able to upgrade to Angular 16 if you do this.

Answer (score 5):

There is a pull request on file-saver to use es modules but it's almost a year old now so I don't know if it's going to happen. [The pull request is here.](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/pull/602) You could also use the repository of the pull request, but it's behind the original repo.
There is also [another repo here](https://github.com/cipchk/ngx-filesaver) which is called ngx-filesaver and uses FileSaver.js. I haven't tried it so I don't know if it will fix the issue, or if it is even any good.

### Update

I tried ngx-filesaver and it seems to just wrap FileSaver.js in an Angular Module. So whilst it gives you a service to use which is more inline with the rest of your angular code, it doesn't deal with the commonJS or AMD dependency warning.